# UIView dont retain the Arrays objects

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, nsmutablearray

I have a `UIViewController` that I load every time I click a button:

```
NearMe * temp = [[NearMe alloc] initWithNibName: @"NearMe" bundle:nil];
```

I parse some XML with locations and then assign the values to an `NSMutableArray`, which populates a `UITableView`.

I parse the XML on the `viewDidLoad` method, but I don't need to parse it every time, since the value is not going to change. I only want to parse it if the array is `nil`, so I put the following check in:

```
if (allLocations == nil) ....
```

So that the XML is only parsed if necessary, but every time I press the back button (in the `UINavigationController`) it erases all the objects in the array.... I don't have any idea why this is happening...

Comment: Can we see the `viewDidLoad` there are a few things that can be going wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your app is creating a new `NearMe` instance each time, the `allLocations` instance variable will always be `nil` in `viewDidLoad` (which, by the way, is only called if the `_view` instance variable is `nil`).

If you don't want to recreate the array each time, your app will need to cache it somewhere else. A couple of possibilities would be to store the array in the object that creates the `NearMe` instance, or to store it in a static variable.

Comment: Another possibility to consider, avoiding keeping it all in memory is to dump the `NSArray` out to a `plist` once the XML has been parsed the first time.